# Annotate segments of correlation matrix plot using a color bar

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, correlation, axes, annotate

I want to annotate segments of the x & y axes of a correlation matrix plot in MATLAB using a color bar like in the image shown below:

[goal correlation plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6b9h.png)

This is the code I have right now:

```
b = imagesc(data);
hold on
title('Correlation plot', 'FontSize', 14); % set title
colormap('jet'); % set the colorscheme
colorbar; % enable colorbar
hold off
```

which outputs the following plot:

[current correlation plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VbBY.png)

How would I go about including the color bar on the x & y axes in the first image?